# Skip MissingPropertyException while using GroovyShell.evaluate

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

Is there a way to skip `MissingPropertyException` while using `GroovyShell.evaluate`?

```
def sharedData = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(sharedData)
shell.evaluate("a=5; b=1") // works fine

// How to not get MissingPropertyException, or silently ignore property 'a'
shell.evaluate("a; b=1") // MissingPropertyException for 'a'
```

I know about the Expando solution, is there a way to do it without defining a class?

Comment: "is there a way to do it without defining a class?" - What is it that you want `a` to evaluate to if you refer to it in the script but never define it?

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown. I just want to skip evaluating `a`.

Comment: " I just want to skip evaluating a" - The language doesn't support that.  If you evaluate a series of statements like `a; b=1`, there is no way to tell Groovy not to evaluate `a`.  The presence of `a` in the script is an explicit request that it be evaluated.

Comment: You can make it evaluate to an empty `String`, `null`, the number zero, or any other default value you like, but you can't skip evaluating it altogether.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks, that should be alright. Do you have some sample code?

Comment: "Thanks, that should be alright. Do you have some sample code?" - I can create one for you.  What is it that you would like `a` to evaluate to when you evaluate something like `a; b=1`?

Answer (score 0):

A very minimal approach would be to override `Binding.getVariable`.
Note that this is very straight forward: "all exceptions" are ignored - you might want to have better logging or more accurate error handling.

```
import groovy.lang.*

class NoOpBinding extends Binding {
    @Override
    Object getVariable(String name) {
        try {
            return super.getVariable(name)
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            println "Ignoring variable=`$name`"
            return null
        }
    }
}

def shell = new GroovyShell(new NoOpBinding())
shell.evaluate("a; b=1") // MissingPropertyException for 'a'
// → Ignoring variable=`a`
println shell.getVariable('b')
// → 1
```

Comment: I won't post another answer since your one solves the problem. There is one small improvement you could suggest in your answer - `new Binding([:].withDefault { null })` This way you can use the existing `Binding` class with a map that returns `null` for bindings that don't exist. Just a few less lines of code to write :-) Good job anyway!

Comment: This does not address the question "is there a way to do it without defining a class?".  @ic10503 Do you want to do this without introducing a new class/type?

Comment: @cftrick thanks for your answer. How is it any better than defining a new class that extends `Expando`?

Comment: @ic10503 You mean the approach, you state in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826801/get-json-from-groovy-object-script-with-missing-properties , where you claim it does not work? This at least works (well it will not in your other question but for different reasons). If your homework assignment forbids defining a class, then the approach Szymon suggested in the first comment works too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def binding = [:].withDefault { }
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding as Binding)

shell.evaluate 'a; b=1'
```